# conversion to dalvik format with error 1

Tags: android

I am getting following error

Dx uncaought translation error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded 
and then aborting

so what should i do??

Comment: It might be more helpful if you can explain in what context you're getting this error.

Comment: please post the error log